# запрос пароля в bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, source-tree

Ввожу команду в SourсeTree через терминал

```
$ git push
```

После чего мне выводит *Password for **url***:
По идее тут надо ввести пароль, как я понял, но у меня не вводится ни один символ, работает только Enter, но если его нажать, выполнится переход на новую строку и выведет:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'url'
```

Почему не работает ввод пароля и как это исправить?

Comment: Не пользовался SourceTree, но часто в терминалах при вводе пароля символы не выводятся на экран в целях безопасности, чтобы никто не подсмотрел ваш пароль. По идее вам просто нужно набрать свой пароль и нажать Enter.

Comment: К сожалению, не вышло

Comment: @MichaelRadionov, оформите, пожалуйста, написанное вами, в виде ответа. это *правильный буквальный* ответ на вопрос (ответ с предложением использовать аутентификацию по ключу тоже верен, но он как бы «расширенный»).

Comment: @andrew, вероятно, вы либо ошиблись с вводом пароля, либо успели нажать какие-то клавиши между *enter*-ом, которым запустили команду `git push`, и собственно паролем. впрочем, второй случай вполне подпадает под определение «ошиблись с паролем».

Comment: @alexander barakin, я не раз вводил по символу, проверяя каждое нажатие

Comment: @andrew, гхм, скажем так: флуктуации, вызванные квантовомеханическими эффектами, ещё, конечно, никто не отменял. если у вас в системе в результате неизвестных факторов в поле ввода пароля самопроизвольно попадают какие-то символы, кооторые вы и удаляете клавишей *backspace*, то вы нашли подходящее решение проблемы. кстати, использование аутентификации по ключу, которое вам предложили в ответе, поможет вам избавиться от этих «флуктуаций» буквально «коренным образом»: пароль вообще не будет запрашиваться.

Answer (score 7):

#### Причина

При обычном использовании данная ошибка возникает тогда и только тогда, когда пользователь ошибается при вводе пароля (то, что он "не вводится" - так всегда было, есть и будет на **UNIX**-подобных системах при просьбе подтвердить свои полномочия, т.е. ввести пароль). **git** разрабатывался [теми же людьми](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds), которые делали **Linux**, так что они одной культуры.

#### Первый способ

1. Проверить **Caps Lock** и **язык**.
2. Аккуратно написать пароль.

#### Второй способ

1. Написать пароль.
2. Скопировать пароль.
3. Вставить пароль.

#### Замечания

Control-буква, Alt-буква и стрелки тоже могут трактоваться как символы.

#### Опция

Можешь также воспользоваться этим гайдом

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Чтобы добавить **ssh** ключ на **bitbucket**. Тогда пароль не придется вводить каждый раз.

Comment: @andrew, я расширил ответ. Прошу ознакомиться. В зависимости от операционной системы ответ звучал бы чуть-чуть по-разному. Я писал как пользователь **Debian** и **OS X**.

Comment: меня Windows. Я правда всё это проделывал, получалось только если сначала очистить строку

Comment: Скорее всего это значит, при прочих равных, что лучше Atlassian's SourceTree не пользоваться. Я лично перестал пользоваться какими бы то ни было GUI для git, и на своей виндовой машине пользовался исключительно **Cygwin** и **VirtualBox**. Проблема может также возникнуть с тем, что ctrl+v оно распознает как ^V символ, а чистое введение пароля совершается после того, как кликнишь на окно и нажмешь какой-нибудь символ. Либо просто иногда переходишь в другое окно случайно. Не знаю. Но стереть все что бы там ни было это выход из любового положения к начальной конфигурации, это так.

Comment: я использую SourceTree только для того, чтобы запускать терминал и работать в нём

Answer (score 3):

Часто в терминалах при вводе пароля символы не выводятся на экран в целях безопасности, чтобы никто не подсмотрел ваш пароль. По идее, после того как появится предложение о вводе пароля `Password for 'url':`, вам просто нужно набрать свой пароль и нажать Enter.

Если быть более точным (и если я не ошибаюсь), то вводимые символы все равно выводятся на экран, но просто цветом фона терминала.

Comment: Символы совсем не выводятся - видно, что курсор в таких случаях не двигается.