# Не вводится пароль в git bash

Tags: git

Когда я в git bash выполняю команду `$ git push origin master`, то после этого мне нужно вводить мои логин и пароль от GitHub. Проблема в том, что логин вводится, а пароль нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: проверти соединение с GitHub  `ssh -l git github.com`

Comment: возможные дубликаты вопроса: [запрос пароля в bitbucket](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437963/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-bitbucket) или [Не могу ввести пароль в терминале](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/442416/178576)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в первом вопросе принятый ответ неверен, к сожалению.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, я бы не сказал, что этот ответ в корне неверен: нажатие `backspace` **до** ввода пароля ничем повредить не сможет.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну да, ещё можно перед вводом пароля перекреститься и трижды плюнуть через левое плечо — тоже не повредит. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пароль при вводе просто не отображается. Но вводится.

Answer (score 4):

Настройте авторизацию по ключам и забудьте про HTTP в гите. Но если это по каким-то причинам невозможно, переложите ввод паролей на IDE.

Comment: третий вариант: [воспользоваться](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6031214/4827341) *ms/windows*-аналогом [тёплого лампового `.netrc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html).