# клонирование репозитория с bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

на bitbucket есть репозиторий, жму на кнопку клонировать, копирую предлагаемую ссылку. Далее в терминале вставляю ссылку жму enter предлагает ввести логин и пароль ввожу логин и пароль от аккаунта на bitbucket. Консоль замирает с надписью:

> F:\OpenServer\domains\папка
>     λ git clone
>   [https://адрес](https://%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81) репозитория.git
>   Cloning into
>   'папка'...
>    Password for 'https:/адрес/': | - мигает курсор текст не вводится

И так замирает, жмешь enter - пишет:

> remote: Empty password fatal: Authentication failed for
>   '[https://адрес/](https://%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81/)'

UPD: попробовал ввести пароль. В ответ:

> remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.

Comment: Ввод пароля не отображается в целях безопасности. Просто введите пароль и нажмите Enter.

Comment: remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile. Вот так пишет

Comment: @pepel_xD скорее всего вы ошиблись с вводом пароля. Проверьте раскладку и капс.

Comment: @pepel_xD ну как, удалось починить? Вообще, рекомендую настроить ssh-ключи и не мучиться с вводом паролей.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin да, непонятно как то получилось.... то ли сервис тупил, то ли я.... Думаю выйду из учетки на сервисе, что бы посмотреть войдет ли он под теми паролями что ввожу для клонирования.... так он не выпускал меня (не разлогинивался), затем вообще начал ересь писать какую-то, на следующий день и в учетку зашел, и репозиторий без проблем склонировал

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [запрос пароля в bitbucket](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437963/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-bitbucket)